# TFSBranchToolVsExtension Exection of Action ConnectSourceControl Fails

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, branching-and-merging

I downloaded [the TFSBranchTool VS Extension Project](http://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/96222).

Rebuilt and Installed, but when I try to apply Initial Structure I get the following Error:

**Exection Error:**

```
Exection of Action 'ConnectSourceControl' Failed. Details: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.AlLMRangers.BranchTool.SourceControlWrapper......
```

Any idea what might be causing the problem ? I tried on 2 different Servers! , I got the latest Update of VS2012.

I got VS2012 SDK installed and Vs2012 ObjectModel too, not sure what I'm missing!

Comment: Forwarded the message to the appropriate people in the ALM Ranger team.

Answer (score 2):

We have posted an update to the sample code on http://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/releases/view/96222, which addresses this bug.

The issue was that Microsoft.ALMRangers.BranchTool.SourceControlWrapper.dll was missed in VSIX package. As action execution engine using MEF to load actions, it has no direct references to actions implementation assembly.

Vladimir from the team fixed the issue by specifying assembly as the MEF asset in the VS extension’s manifest file. Now it’s redistributed inside the extension package.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that you have the file `Microsoft.ALMRangers.BranchTool.SourceControlWrapper.dll`
in the following folder:

> > %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\Microsoft. ALM Rangers\TfsBranchToolVSExtension\1.0

If its not there - try deleting the `TfsBranchToolVSExtension` and re-install the VSIX.